# Why was the PlaceHolderFragment class added to android's main Activity?

Tags: java, android

I recently re-downloaded the ADT bundle and noticed that when I crate an empty activity, the code has changed from

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

to include more lines of code. Specifically this..

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

with

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
```

added inside the `onCreate` function after `setContentView`

Being new to android, any kind of change will have me a bit wondering why and what's going on so I commented out all the new lines of code and everything still works fine. 
The question of course is what is the purpose or function of the new code and how does it fit in here..

Comment: just encouraging the use of fragments

Comment: What setbacks would I encounter if I choose to ignore the use of fragments?

Comment: None if you just want simple screen based applications, if you want to be able to reuse your stuff, use fragments.